# Search through two dataframes in R to match values from one column to the other

Tags: r, matching

That title might be confusing so it might be easier to show what I'm trying to do. This is what the first data frame looks like:

| city | code | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dallas | NA | 18 |
| chicago | NA | 24 |
| new york | NA | 13 |
| dallas | NA | 90 |

And the second data frame looks like this:

| city | code | feet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dallas | 1 | 1000 |
| austin | 2 | 1300 |
| cupertino | 3 | 908 |
| chicago | 4 | 2132 |
| las vegas | 5 | 1128 |
| new york | 6 | 1133 |

Ultimately I want to input the code values from the second data frame into the first data frame based on the cities, so the first data frame should ultimately look like this:

| city | code | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dallas | 1 | 18 |
| chicago | 4 | 24 |
| new york | 6 | 13 |

How do I do that without for loops? I know how to do it with for loops, but ultimately that is really inefficient and I'm looking for an efficient way that is a line or two long.  For further clarification this is not my actual data but I figured it would be the simplest way to convey my issue.

Comment: Try `merge(df1[-2], df2)[c(1, 3, 2)]`. In `df1` you have two rows for `dallas`, but only one in the expected result. What is the criterion to choose it?

Comment: I want to do it automatically, so df1 will find when the city has a match in df2 then input the code from df2 into df1. df2 should just be used as a lookup table for df1.

Answer (score 0):

This will give exactly your desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
full_join(df1 %>%
            mutate(id = row_number()), df2) %>% 
  group_by(city, code, population, id) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  fill(code, .direction="down") %>% 
  slice(2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
  city      code population
  <chr>    <int>      <int>
1 dallas       1         18
2 chicago      4         24
3 new york     6         13
```